# How to correctly display outlined icon in Android Bottom Navigation View

Tags: android, android-bottomnavigationview

My current Android application employs `com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView`

I have four icons, one of which is the standard android vector image for `person outline`

[image]

which looks like above

however in the Apps bottom navigation window it resembles the following:-

[image]

my xml layout for the navigation bar resembles this:-

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/home_bottom_navigation_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_navigation_bar_color"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_navigation_bar_color"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />
```

What have I done wrong to not have the outlined icon display correctly?

Comment: I don't think Bottom navigation view fills the icon. Maybe you should double check to make sure you are using the same drawable you intend to use.

Comment: @Qunata, good thought, however I've double checked it and I am employing the outlined version of the icon. Maybe bottom navigation bar doesnt correctly support vector graphics?

Comment: It happens because the icons are tinted by `app:itemIconTint`.You have to use `bottomNavigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);`  but it works for all the icons.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
bottomNavView.itemIconTintList = null
```

Answer (score 0):

With `app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_navigation_bar_color"` you set the color to the icon. I think that this might solve your problem. See the docs: https://material.io/develop/android/components/bottom-navigation/

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong: Icon tint doesn't affects the transparent areas. Or does it ?